# find the set of all positive integers n for which there is a real matrix A of dimension n×n such that $A^{−1}=−A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Need to find the set of all positive integers $n$ for which there is a real matrix $A$ of dimension $n\times n$ such that $A^{−1}=−A$.

**Tried:** 
let $\lambda$ be an eigen value of A then we have 
$\lambda + \lambda^{-1}=0$
$\implies$ $\lambda^{2}=-1$$\implies$ $\lambda=\pm i$
now I am not getting how I do it.

Comment: You're doing fine so far, now here's a hint: the complex roots of a real polynomial always come in conjugate pairs.  (There's also an easier way to arrive at the same conclusion by looking at the determinant.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial has no real roots, so it must be of even degree. Hence $n$ is even. To finish, construct a square matrix of any even size that squares to $-I$.